# How to change title color of UIButton when clicked?

Tags: ios

I have a view and I created some 8 buttons programmatically in that. The title color of buttons is white color. I want to change color of button title to green color when it is clicked. And if i click any other button, the previously clicked button title color should become white and current button title color should become green.

How to do that?

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate question.  Thanks for the correct answer @Bordz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Initialize all your buttons like this

```
[mybutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mybutton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(onclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then change the selected state of you button when clicked

```
-(void)onclick:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `IBAction` for all of the buttons, create a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *currentButton`. In the action do the following:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *buttonSender = (UIButton *)sender;

    [self.currentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.currentButton = buttonSender;
    [self.currentButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set control state of buttons :

```
[btnOk setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnOk setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnOk setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```